# Asp.Net RadioButtonList Selected ListItem Not Recognized on Page Revisit

Tags: asp.net, database, radiobuttonlist, listitem

On my shipping address page there are two RadioButtonList ListItems (code shown below) that write to a database true or false based on user input.

The first time a user selects a value and moves to the next step of the checkout process their ship to address type is stored correctly (true / false) in a database. If they go back to the shipping address page, select the opposite ListItem and move on to the next checkout page, their updated shipping type is not changed in the database. It is as if the ListItem does not recognize the user's radiobutton selection has changed when revisiting the page.

Can someone please help figure this one out?

**ShippingAddress.ascx**

```
<asp:RadioButtonList id="ShipToAddressType" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem Value="0" id="businessShipping">My shipping address is a business.</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="1" id="residenceShipping">My shipping address is a residence.</asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

**ShippingAddress.ascx.cs**

```
if (residenceShipping.Selected == true)
    shippingAddress.Residence = true;
else
    shippingAddress.Residence = false;
```

**ShippingAddress.ascx.cs Page_Load**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    User user = Token.Instance.User;

    Address shipAddress = null;

    foreach (Address tempAddress in user.Addresses) if (tempAddress.Nickname == "Shipping") shipAddress = tempAddress;

    // sets radio button of return users previously selected ship type
    if (shipAddress != null)
    {
        if (shipAddress.Residence == false)
        {
            ShipToAddressType.SelectedIndex = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            ShipToAddressType.SelectedIndex = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the problem suggests a misunderstanding / mistake done related to page life cycle. with the given information cant help!

Comment: Might need a little more info...  What does your PageLoad Event Handler in the code-behind look like?

Comment: I edited the post, adding the page load event handler above. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move the code in `Page_Load` to `Page_Init`. Otherwise `ViewState` won't work and you won't get change events. View state is loaded after `Init` before `PreLoad`.

You should also wrap your init code in a `IsPostBack` check. Although I may misunderstand what you are doing here.

```
protected void Page_Init(EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        User user = Token.Instance.User;

        Address shipAddress = null;

        foreach (Address tempAddress in user.Addresses)
        {
            if (tempAddress.Nickname != "Shipping")
            {
                continue;
            }
            ShipToAddressType.SelectedIndex = 1;
        }
    }
    ShipToAddressType.SelectedIndexChanged += ShipToAddressType_SelectedIndexChanged;
}

void ShipToAddressType_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // save the new state to database

    // redirect to enforce refresh of saved state
    Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl);
}
```

Comment: Fitting handle CodeKing. Thanks for the quick response and correct answer to what was a long headscratcher for me.